# Java How do you store an array list of objects in a file?

Tags: java, file, document, record

How do you store an array list of objects into a file, so that it may be later read back from the file and retain its data?

<strike>I am attempting to write a program in Java that uses a GUI to allow the user to input a record, i.e. Contact Info (with a name, an image, contact information), and then store it in a file. Later, they are able to read the entire file as a list of contacts.</strike>

I am wondering what the best way to incorporate that into an alphabetically sorted file, so that when read, it will always display the items in the correct order. Currently I save each contact as an individual file, then just load them as they appear in the directory. Is there a way to store them into a single file, then somehow access each record consecutively? I guess what I am really asking is whether it is possible in Java to save an object into a text/data file, then have it read back as an 'object'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with serialized objects, why not serialize a whole ArrayList etc.?
If the file isn´t getting big (100MB, 1GB, 10GB...), then there shouldn´t be a problem
with simply store and load everything just like that.

Comment: I have no idea what this means, really, but after twenty minutes of Googling, serializing an ArrayList seems promising. Thanks for heading me in the right direction. Now all I have to do is figure out what that means. :p

Comment: How do you store multiple records in your program (while the data is in RAM)? Array, ArrayList, LinkedList, ...? And, i assumed you´re using the built-in Java serialization. Re-reading the question, this might not be the case. So, how are the records currently stored in their files?

Comment: Currently, I load them into an ArrayList each time, but they are currently stored each in their own, individual file. Also, the only thing I know about serialization right now is that Eclipse makes me serialize my Swing frame, but I have no idea why or what it does.

Comment: But how they are stored in their files? Java serialization (ObjectOutputStream)? A text file with one line for the name, one line for the adress...? Separated with something other than newlines? XML? ...? If it is some text thing, how is the image fitting in? Raw binary after the text, hex data, base64, ...? (Jpg, ...?)

Comment: I save them in text files with each line being a field in the program, and the image is saved as a filepath to the image itself. I don't know how to save the image as anything else.

Comment: Ok. If you want to stick with that...i don´t understand the problem. Currently, you´re writing a file per ArrayList entry, with a fixed count/order of lines with information in each file. Lets say 4 lines per file: Name, Address, Image path, and another thing. If you have 10 Arraylist entries, what´s difficult in writing one file with 40 lines instead of 10 files with 4 lines each?

Answer (score 0):

There's not better way...there are ways... e.g. parse the information into a XML file or use a simplier one like a CSV file
Assuming that you sorted the values previously